# What is the best possible approach to connect seriate node.js with a web application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, node-seriate

I am actually involved in a POC and looking to build a web app which can display SQL results after hitting a button. Got to know that seriate node.js is a good platform for this. But unable to find out how to link these components. Any help towards this would be appreciable.

Comment: Is it mysql db which you are using with nodejs application

Comment: its Microsoft SQLServer

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below code

```
var webconfig = {
    user: 'login',
    password: 'sa@123',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'TestDB',

    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
    }
}

var express = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var connection = new sql.Connection(webconfig, function(err) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection); 
    request.query('select * from Users', function(err, recordset) {
       if(err)      // ... error checks 
            console.log('Database connection error');

    console.dir("User Data: "+recordset);
    });
});


app.listen(port);
console.log(port+' is the magic port');
```

Comment: `module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mssql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/msudhera/check.js:13:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
`

Comment: got this error after executing.I was running earlier with seriate and the query ran with but it was not related to UI

`var sql = require("seriate");
var config = {
                "server":"localhost",
                "user": "username",
                "password":"xyz",
                "database":"DBname",
};

sql.setDefaultConfig( config );
sql.execute({
query:"select * from job"}).then( function(results){
console.log(results);
}, function(err){
console.log("Something bas happened:", err);
}); `

Comment: Yes, I just installed mssql, http, tedious. It was asking for these modules.
now getting the error:

/mssql/lib/tedious.js:109
      index,
           ^
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,**
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)


in inbuilt tedious.js. Not sure with what to replace the comma.